# Generate Propel migration file for data entry alone

Tags: propel, data-migration

Is it possible to generate a Propel migration file without modifying the schema? I only need to insert values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a blank migration like this:

`propel migration:create`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just call the `diff` target in the Propel 1 command, which will create a migration class.

(Propel on MySQL for me always creates spurious differences e.g. between `FLOAT` and `DECIMAL`, which I delete manually. I don't know if it would refuse to create a class if no differences were found).

Answer (score -3):

Propel migration system is not able to insert values, only update your database structure when you update your schema.

If you use Symfony2, you can use the command propel:fixture:* to insert data for test purpose.

Comment: In the Propel migration documentation, there is a section about migrating data:  

_Propel automatically executes the preUp() and postUp() migration before and after the structure migration. If you want to add data migration, that's the place to put the related code._

Comment: This is not to insert data, but to migrate your data, like storing them in PHP array, transform them, and reinsert.

Comment: See [documentation](http://propelorm.org/Propel/documentation/10-migrations.html#migrating-data).

I don't need fixture data there. Let's say you store a categories list depending on range parameters. I need to change the ranges, or add categories. What is the correct way to do this if not using Propel data migrations ?